# React: Controlling input value with both props and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given a React component with a controlled input, I would like to be able to:

1. Set the value of the input from the parent's state
2. Allow the user to change the input to any value
3. Update the parent's state only after the user submits and input passes validation.

I can accomplish 1 and 2 with the snippet below, but since the value came into the ChildComponent via props, I'm not sure how I can change the input value *without* changing the value of myInput on the parent.

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component
{
    render(){
        return <input type="text" value={this.props.inputValue} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
    }  
    handleChange(e){
        this.props.onInputChange(e.target.value);
    }
    handleSubmit(){
        // do some validation here, it it passes...
        this.props.handleSubmit();
    }
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {myInput: ""};
    }
    render(){
        return <ChildComponent inputValue={this.state.myInput} onInputChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
    }
    handleChange(newValue){
        this.setState({myInput: newValue});
    }
    handleSubmit(){
        // do something on the server
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Then you just need to move the state to the child component, instead of rendering from `props.inputValue` directly. Basically you'd just move `handleChange` to the child.

Set the initial value from `props.inputValue` in `getInitialState`, then make sure to update the child state in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: This makes sense.  I've been trying to use state sparingly outside of top level components in the spirit of Flux and having a single source of truth.  I think this is different though considering the value of the input is really internal to the component itself until the user submits.

Comment: @Sean Yeah, I agree with the principle of keeping state centralized in top-level components. But in this case, the parent does not really care about the current value of the input, while the child DOES need to keep track of it (for validation purposes).

Comment: While it's good to keep application state centralized, the value of a text field isn't really application state, it's view state. And that does belong inside the component. A good rule of thumb is that if you have state that is no longer relevant when a component unmounts, it should be state local to that component.

Answer (score 4):

## componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

> This lifecycle was previously named componentWillReceiveProps. That
> name will continue to work until version 17. Use the
> rename-unsafe-lifecycles codemod to automatically update your
> components.

Use something like this instead:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {       
        if (this.props.yourObj != null && prevProps.yourObj !== this.props.yourObj) {
            this.setState({
                yourStateObj = this.props.yourObj
            });
        }
}
```